# Button in Panel not calling Parent Onclick Event

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, user-controls

The title is not entirely accurate, I have a Container control with a property of type `PanelControlCollection` which is basically a collection of `PanelControl`:

```
public class PanelControl : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class PanelControlCollection : Collection<PanelControl> {}
```

My custom User Control:

```
public partial class FormSlideShow : BaseUserControl
{
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public PanelControlCollection Panels Title { get; set; }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        foreach(var panel in Panels)
        {
            ContentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(
                new LiteralControl("<fieldset class='step' Title='" + panel.Title + "'>"));
            ContentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(panel);
            ContentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(
                new LiteralControl("</fieldset>"));
        }
        base.Render(writer);
    }
}
```

I wanted to be able to make a custom control and add pages in markup (code in Default.aspx):

```
<ctrl:FormSlide runat="server" ID="frmSlide">
    <Panels>
        <ctrl:PanelControl runat="server" ID="page1"><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTest" OnClick="btnTest_Onclick" /></ctrl:PanelControl>
        <ctrl:PanelControl runat="server" ID="PanelControl1">Page 2</ctrl:PanelControl>
    </Panels>
</ctrl:FormSlide>
```

My question is, if I want to host the control in a normal aspx page, how can I connect my Button control (btnTest) to the OnClick event in the code behind of default.aspx? If I put a normal Panel control with a button I can attach events to the onclick but not with my custom control.

btw here is my code behind on default.aspx, the code which I want to run but can't:

```
protected void btnTest_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you cannot attach the onclick of a button inside your custom control, because it is not exposed. If you expose the event in a public property of your custom control, you should be able to attach it further in a parent page.

Comment: @Uw Concept Thanks for your reply. The button and the event are both added in the parent page. The custom control is just a template for paging but the actual content is all in the calling page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving this:

```
foreach(var panel in Panels)
{
    ContentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(
        new LiteralControl("<fieldset class='step' Title='" + panel.Title + "'>"));
    ContentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(panel);
    ContentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(
        new LiteralControl("</fieldset>"));
}
base.Render(writer);
```

into `OnInit` rather than `Render`. I think `Render` is too late to register PostBack events with ASP.NET. I was able to reproduce your issue and then resolve it by moving that piece of code.

Of course, `base.Render(writer);` should be replaced with `base.OnInit(e);`

Comment: Not sure this is what you're looking for based on your last comment. Knowing that the button is on the Default.aspx, what are you having trouble with in regards to binding the Click event?

Comment: Yeah it's a good solution but I want to be able to put buttons in the user control from the parent page, i.e. the control doesn't know in advance what buttons will be placed in it's template. I have an onclick in the default.aspx that's not running when I click the button.

Comment: Sorry about that, try this one.